# Nondeterministic (random) rounding based on decimal places

Tags: c#, rounding

I want to do something like this:

```
return Utils.RandomDouble() < value - Math.Floor(value) : (int)Math.Floor(value) : (int)Math.Ceil(value);
```

Hard to google it ;) Is there any literature about such kind of rounding mechanism or a name for it?

Just a little background:
We use it for a game where we have health based on integers (hitpoints) but calculate the damages based on doubles to be more exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Banker's rounding could be ok, thought it's not random: it just tries to uniformly distribute deviations in case the input is somehwat spread (say a stddev of >1)

However, you're describing

#### Stochastic Rounding [(WikiPedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Stochastic_rounding)

> Another unbiased tie-breaking method is stochastic rounding:
> If the fractional part of y is .5, choose q randomly among y + 0.5 and y − 0.5, with equal probability.
>
> Like round-half-to-even, this rule is essentially free of overall bias; but it is also fair among even and odd q values. On the other hand, it introduces a random component into the result; performing the same computation twice on the same data may yield two different results. Also, it is open to nonconscious bias if humans (rather than computers or devices of chance) are "randomly" deciding in which direction to round.

Somewhat related: Alternating tie-breaking (can still introduce bias, but lacks the random component)

Comment: Thanks, since we might get a lot of "hits" with say 1.5 damage, the Bankers Rounding will not represent ~15 damage after 10 hits.

Comment: @Tarion a good case for either stochastic or alternating tie breaking, IYAM.